# Drawing on website icon in browser tab?

Tags: google-chrome

Both GMail (with the "Unread message icon" Labs extension) and PagerDuty draw a notification count on the icon displayed in the title tab in Chrome.

How can I make my web page do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple. You basically use a canvas element to "draw" the icon and write a text over it, then get the resulting image as a data URI and set it as your page favicon.

For example:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var unreadEmails = 8; // Just an example
  
  var canvas = document.getElementById("my-canvas");
  var favicon = document.getElementById("my-favicon");

  canvas.width = 16; // Favicons are usually 16x16
  canvas.height = 16;
  
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var imageObj = new Image();
  
  imageObj.onload = function(){
    // When the <img> is loaded, draw it into the canvas
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);

    // Setup an small font size for the text and draw it over the icon image
    context.font = "11px sans-serif";
    context.fillText(unreadEmails, 4, 4);

    // Finally get result as an base64 encoded png
    var modifiedIcon = canvas.toDataURL();

    // And set it as the href of your favicon tag
    favicon.href = modifiedIcon;
  };
  
  imageObj.src = "my-favicon-16-px.png"; 
};
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link id="my-favicon" rel="shortcut icon" href="my-favicon-16-px.png">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- hidden because it's just used to render the icon with the text -->
    <canvas id="my-canvas" style="display:none;">
</body>
</html>
```

Obviously, this code will need some tweaking to give the desired result. But its good enough to give you an idea on how they do it.

Some websites go even further and use the favicon as an part of the UI. [MixCloud](https://www.mixcloud.com/juanramongimenezsanchez36/chillout-lounge-music-buddha-mix/) for example, displays the current playback status on the favicon (press play to see it in action).

Comment: I had to (on Chrome 46 on Linux, anyway) use `favicon.href = modifiedIcon` (from http://blog.roomanna.com/09-24-2011/dynamically-coloring-a-favicon)

Comment: @RogerLipscombe yes you're a right, tags like `<link rel="shortcut icon" ...>` uses `href`, not `src`. I've fixed that, thanks!